# Как отправить запрос Get через Axios с параметрами json внутри?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, fastapi

Как отправить запрос Get через Axios с параметрами json внутри? Делаю этот запрос, выдает ошибку 422, а если делаю пост запрос с такими же параметрами, всё работает исправно. Можно конечно данные через post получать, но это костыльно

```
export const getUserInfo = createAsyncThunk('userState/getUserInfo', async (tok) => {
    const config = {
        "token": tok
    }
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://backend-pizza-test.herokuapp.com/api/get/userinfo', config )
    return data
})
```

Comment: Если кратко - никак. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) И почему вы считаете, что передача запросов через `POST` костыльна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const getUserInfo = createAsyncThunk('userState/getUserInfo', async (tok) => {
    const config = {
        params: {
            token: tok // Параметры добавляются в объект params
        }
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get('https://backend-pizza-test.herokuapp.com/api/get/userinfo', config);
    return data;
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

GET-запрос может содержать параметры, которые в URL выглядят так:

```
https://site.com/?foo=bar
```

При использовании Axios запрос подобного рода можно выполнить так:

```
axios.get('https://site.com/?foo=bar')
```

Того же эффекта можно достичь, настроив свойство params в объекте с параметрами:

```
axios.get('https://site.com/', {
  params: {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
})
```